# how to set scope of controller after socket.io message event in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

this is my main.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) { 
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); // enable pushState
   $routeProvider.when('/', { 
      templateUrl: '/app.html',
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
   });
   $routeProvider.when('/another/route', { 
      templateUrl: '/deep.html',
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
   });
});
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
  socket.on('sendCustomer', function (data) {
    console.log(data);`
    //here i want to set controller scope 
  });
app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) { 
    $scope.model = { 
       message: 'This is my app!!!' 
    };
    $scope.getCustomer = function(imageUrl) {
        alert("here i have to send command to socket io ");
        socket.emit('getCustomer', { });
    };

});
```

this is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Egghead Videos</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/vendor/foundation/foundation.min.css'>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app='app'>
   <ng-view></ng-view> 
</div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='/vendor/angularjs/angular.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/socket.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/main.js'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the app.html

```
<h1>{{model.message}}</h1>

<a href="" ng-click="getCustomer()">Get Customer Data</a>

<!-- here i want to do ng-repeat of customer data -->
```

this is my server .js

var express = require('express');

```
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var fs = require('fs');
server.listen(8000);
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(app.router);

app.get('/', function (req, res) { 
  res.set('content-type', 'text/html');
  res.send(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html', 'utf8'));
});
app.get('/another/route', function (req, res) { 
  res.set('content-type', 'text/html');
  res.send(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html', 'utf8'));
});
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
  socket.on('getCustomer', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('sendCustomer', [{ name: 'c1' },{ name: 'c2' }]);
  });
});
```

so when sendCustomer event on client is fired in main.js , i want to show that data in controller throught ng-repeat , can i do that if yes then how ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a service like that to handle Socket.IO:

```
app.factory('socket', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
  var socket = io.connect();

  return {
    on: function (eventName, callback) {
      function wrapper() {
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          callback.apply(socket, args);
        });
      }

      socket.on(eventName, wrapper);

      return function () {
        socket.removeListener(eventName, wrapper);
      };
    },

    emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
      socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          if(callback) {
            callback.apply(socket, args);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Then you can use it in your controller:

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', 'socket', function ($scope, socket) { 
    socket.on('sendCustomer', function (data) {
      $scope.customers.push(data);
    });
    $scope.model = { 
       message: 'This is my app!!!' 
    };
    $scope.customers = [];

    $scope.getCustomer = function(imageUrl) {
        alert("here i have to send command to socket io ");
        socket.emit('getCustomer', { });
    };
});
```

And finally in app.html:

```
<div ng-repeat="customer in customers">{{customer}}</div>
```

By the way, you could just use a REST API to do the same thing easily, but I'm guessing you want to try Socket.IO.

Comment: quand j'utilise votre code, à partir du moment ou j'ajoute la partie "socket" dans le controller d'Angular. Cela détruit le rendu de la page. Est-ce que vous auriez une idée de ce qui cause cela? Et ou de comment trouver ce qui cloche?

Answer (score 2):

First off, if you're going to use anything within a module, you have to pass it in.

```
app.controller('AppCtr', ['$scope', 'socket', function($scope, socket) { ...
```

Because you're doing stuff in socket, outside of Angular, you'll also have to pay attention to $apply() to get these changes to appear inside of Angular.

I could type out more on this, but really, Brian Ford's socket.io seed and related blog post are the best starting points for sockets + express + angular.

- https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io-seed
- http://briantford.com/blog/angular-socket-io.html